# Removing clients from the reactor in Twisted

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

I have a simple TCP client which is connected to twisted using:

```
reactor.connectTCP(host, port, SomeClientFactory())
```

The program is able to receive a HUP signal to trigger a reload. I'd like to basically:

1. Remove the old clients
2. Reload config
3. Create new clients based upon new config

However, I can't seem to find a way to acheive the first of these points. Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IReactorTCP.connectTCP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTCP.html) returns an `IConnector` provider.  As you can see on the [definition of the `IConnector` interface](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IConnector.html), the `disconnect` method will do something like what you want.  You can also use the protocol instance's transport attribute's `loseConnection` method, of course.  The latter would be more suitable if there's any kind of cleanup you want the protocol to do before actually disconnecting, since you could put that work and a call to loseConnection at the end of a method like `shutdown` or `quit` or `cleanup` on the protocol class and then just call that.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the quick response. I do make a call to loseConnection in the protocol and tidy up the actual tcp connection, I also call the stopTrying method of the ReconnectingClientFactory which I am using, however I presumed that the instance of the client factory is still referenced somewhere by the reactor and should be removed if I am never going to use it again. Does the client factory get gced for me or should I remove it somehow?

Comment: I think the reactor doesn't keep track of clients, rather the clients have a reference to the reactor which handles their I/O.

Comment: The reactor keeps track a bit, but once the client connection is closed and the factory is told to stop, that tracking state will be cleaned up and discarded.  Only while the connection is actually established does the reactor know about it.